# can windows service be used to generate & print crystal reports?

Tags: c#, windows, service, crystal-reports

I have got an application that needs to print reports at a distant location connected via the internet. Since there is no network printer we have to send reports generated through email and wait for someone to print them.

I was thinking if I can use windows service to automate the task

I've got the following options

1. get data from SQL Server base on filters transferred from distance location to generate crystal report and print it to the default printer.
2. get the report in pdf format from distance location & print it to the default printer

is any one of the options possible.

I'm asking for some help here since I've not created a windows service up till now for anything

Your guidance is highly applicated

Thanks a lot

Amit Saraf

Comment: windows service has no problem exporting crystal reports to disk. As to if it can print that you have to test depending on your architecture. I.E where I work the services are running with no session open so there is not a single network printer accessible as you need an open domain session in order to have them mapped. If session is open it works. If the printer is directly connected to the computer it might work but that depend if the printer driver are loaded before any sessions are opened. For example I have a ton of Zebra label printer which only work when session is open.

Comment: You mean to say I can add crystal report to windows service as i thought it wont be possible since windows service do not have ui

Comment: Watch out, windows service cannot SHOW a UI not that it cannot use UI elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply will try to create test service and let you know if anything arrise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your application can use the Crystal runtime and trigger a printout or an export of a report without any display to the screen.

Alternatively, the application can use a command line API of several cheap/free 3rd-party Crystal tools (typically, they are called viewers or schedulers) to achieve the same thing. The command line API would allow you to specify the rpt file, parameters, login info, printer destination, export format, export file, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply will try to create test service and let you know if anything arrise

Answer (score 1):

Yess window services generate and print the crystal report:
Firstly you have install the packages from nuget but you have use VS.

Step 1: Create the Database
Step 2: Create the Window Service
Step 3: Install the Windows Service

Also help from this link:
http://aspalliance.com/1917_Automate_delivery_of_Crystal_Reports_With_a_Windows_Service.3

Comment: Thanks for your reply will try to create test service and let you know if anything arrise

Comment: @AmitSaraf yeah tell me anything else <3